# javascript's window.preview function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement the following code which works fine for one input file but I am looking to use same thing using two forms and two different divs.

```js
window.preview = function(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        $(input.files).each(function(){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(this);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $("#messages-list").append("<li class='text-message-img'><img class='thumb' src='" + e.target.result + "'></li>");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="picture-upload">
    <span>
        <img src="images/icons.png">
        Click to upload
    </span>
    <input class="upload" type=file onchange="preview(this);" accept="image/*" value="">
</form>
```

But the problem is I want to use two form that shows in different div.
How can I select two different form input and show the result in two different divs?

Comment: Minified code is great for a production environment, but if you want an answer it's best to make the code as clear as possible. Please always post your code in a human-readable format.

Comment: Your example does not even work for 1 "div" (there are no div's in your html)

Comment: Isn't it appending an html section like "<li class='text-message-img'><img class='thumb' src='"+e.target.result+"'></li>" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the id of the target element to the preview function:

```js
window.preview = function(input, element) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        $(input.files).each(function(){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(this);
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $(element).append("<li class='text-message-img'><img class='thumb' src='" + e.target.result + "'></li>");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="picture-upload">
    <span>
        <img src="images/icons.png">
        Click to upload
    </span>
    <input class="upload" type=file onchange="preview(this, '#messages-list');" accept="image/*" value="">
</form>
```